# does google places api return latest five or oldest five or random five reviews?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I am working with google places api. I want to view all reviews of a business in google place.
But the documentation says that it only returns an array of five reviews.

Now, I want to know is there any way to get all reviews ?
And does google places api return latest five or oldest five or random five reviews ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I last used the the Places API (6 months ago) it would only return the 5 "most helpful" reviews. I can't find in the documentation and verbiage to suggest this was changed to the latest reviews.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults

Update: 
Currently users are requesting a change to the sorting order via the Google Places API feature requests, changing from "most helpful" to latest- http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4258&q=apitype%3APlacesAPI%20type%3AEnhancement%20reviews&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Answer (score 0):

Google places API always returns 5 latest reviews. There are no other way to fetch more than five reviews.

Comment: Not true. It returns the five "most helpful" reviews, not the five latest reviews to be added.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no offering of the Places API that returns more than the top 5 reviews. If you would like to request this feature you can file a Places API - [Feature Request.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request)