# Getting the oldest review in google maps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-maps

I have a datframe df which has a column ''name_address'' which will act as a search prompt. I want to retrive the oldest review and the count of ratings using google API

I used the following query but it is not accurate:

```
    if search_results:
    # Get the place ID of the first result
    place_id = search_results[0].get("place_id")

    # Make API request to fetch place details using Place Details
    details_url = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid={place_id}&key={api_key}"
    details_response = requests.get(details_url)
    place_details = details_response.json().get("result", {})

    # Get the total count of ratings (user_ratings_total)
    rating_count = place_details.get("user_ratings_total", "N/A")
    rating_counts.append(rating_count)

    # Get the ratings list and find the oldest review
    ratings = place_details.get("reviews", [])
    oldest_review_date = "N/A"
    if ratings:
        oldest_rating = min(ratings, key=lambda rating: rating.get("time"))
        oldest_review_unix_time = oldest_rating.get("time")
        oldest_review_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(oldest_review_unix_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    oldest_review_dates.append(oldest_review_date)
else:
    rating_counts.append("N/A")
    oldest_review_dates.append("N/A")
```

Comment: What do you mean by not accurate? not always getting the oldest review per place?

Comment: Yes when there are more count of ratings say >30 then the oldest review is not accurate

Comment: Seems like the API does not always allow you to allow the oldest reviews https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367748/does-google-places-api-return-latest-five-or-oldest-five-or-random-five-reviews

Answer (score 0):

### Places API only returns up to five reviews

There's an ongoing Feature Request in the Public Issue Tracker to request for more than 5 reviews:

https://issuetracker.google.com/35825957

One googler mentioned in the comment that:

> Being able to retrieve all the reviews for a given business is only supported if you are a verified business owner and can be done via the Google My Business API: https://developers.google.com/my-business/

This could also mean that there's a limit to how old the reviews you can get since it is only limited to five.

The [public documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#Place-reviews) describes the review field as such:

> A JSON array of up to five reviews. By default, the reviews are sorted in order of relevance. Use the **reviews_sort** request parameter to control sorting.
>
> - For `most_relevant` (default), reviews are sorted by relevance; the
>   service will bias the results to return reviews originally written in
>   the preferred language.
> - For `newest`, reviews are sorted in
>   chronological order; the preferred language does not affect the sort
>   order.

Though it was mentioned that it is possible to sort the review in chronological order, this does not take away the fact that the API is only limited to 5 results. So this still does not "guarantee" that you will be able to have the **"oldest"** review. What you can have though is the "oldest out of the five".

If you want you can file a feature request to be able to find the oldest review. But you would need to include your use case for Google engineers to consider implementing it, or you can just put your use case in the aforementioned request about having more than 5 reviews.

I hope this information helps.